# How to force a Haskell type to a more general type

Tags: haskell, types, gtk2hs

I am struggling to get the following code past GHC:

```
getFirstChild :: (WidgetClass w1, WidgetClass w2) => w1 -> IO (Maybe w2)
getFirstChild parent = do
   -- check if parent is a container
   if parent `isA` gTypeContainer
      -- if parent is a container get the first child
      then do children <- containerGetChildren $! castToContainer parent
              return $! Just $! children !! 0
      else return Nothing
```

Even though at first glance it looks like a Gtk2hs question, it is really about the Haskell type system.

When I try to compile this code with GHC, I get the following error message:

```
Could not deduce (w2 ~ Widget)
from the context (WidgetClass w1, WidgetClass w2)
  bound by the type signature for
             getFirstChild :: (WidgetClass w1, WidgetClass w2) =>
                              w1 -> IO (Maybe w2)
  at HsFu\Gtk\Widget.hs:(6,4)-(12,28)
  `w2' is a rigid type variable bound by
       the type signature for
         getFirstChild :: (WidgetClass w1, WidgetClass w2) =>
                          w1 -> IO (Maybe w2)
       at HsFu\Gtk\Widget.hs:6:4
Expected type: [w2]
  Actual type: [Widget]
In the first argument of `(!!)', namely `children'
In the second argument of `($!)', namely `children !! 0'
```

The type of `containerGetChildren` is:

```
containerGetChildren :: ContainerClass self => self -> IO [Widget]
```

The `Widget` type is itself an instance of `WidgetClass`, so I do not understand why I cannot have the return type of the `getFirstChild` function specified as `w2` that is an instance of `WidgetClass`.

Is there a way to express this in Haskell without using things like `unsafeCoerce` ?

TIA

Comment: This is a classic stumbling block for people moving from OO languages to Haskell. In OO, you have subtype polymorphism, which is existential: if I return an `Object`, what I'm really saying is that *there exists* some type `T <: Object` that I've returned an instance of. In Haskell, you have type class polymorphism, which is universal: a type is something like `forall a. TC a => Int -> a`, which says that *for every type* that's an instance of `TC`, I can return that type. Another way of phrasing this is that in OO, the choice of type is up to the function; in Haskell, it's up to the caller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there isn't a way. Your declraration

```
getFirstChild :: (WidgetClass w1, WidgetClass w2) => w1 -> IO (Maybe w2)
```

says that your function can return *any* w2 as long as it's in WidgetClass, but that's a lie, because it only returns Widgets. Haskell won't let you mislead the programmer like this.

Suppose that I were importing your module and wrote

```
data MyWodget = ....
instance WidgetClass MyWodget where ....
```

Then it would be reasonable for me to expect from your type signature that your function could return a `Maybe MyWodget` as long as I'd put some MyWodgets inside another MyWodget, but because the function you've used in your definition can only work with Widgets, Haskell can't use it on a MyWodget, and my code would both typecheck and not typecheck.

You won't be *able* to fix this with unsafeCoerce because a MyWodget simply isn't a Widget in any way; haskell typeclasses let you use truly different data types with the same functional interface, so you can't just coerce there.

You could define your own class

```
class FromWidget w where -- not a good name, I admit
    fromWidget :: Widget -> w
```

Then you could use fromWidget to rewrite your function to be more general:

```
getFirstChild :: (WidgetClass w1, FromWidget w2) => w1 -> IO (Maybe w2)
```

and I could use it on MyWodget as long as I make

```
instance FromWidget MyWodget where ....
```

But I deeply doubt that there's a way of making everything in WidgetClass this way. Maybe you can make every WidgetClass thing you're interested in, but maybe you should check if you're actually only interested in Widgets anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I did some checking and it seems that I can get by with returning IO (Maybe Widget) instead of the more generic w2 type.

Answer (score 2):

According to the type of your function your function should work for any `w1` and `w2` belonging to `WidgetClass`. But you are returning a more specific type `Widget`. Whenever you are in such kind of doubts, don't provide the type to the function and see what type `ghci` infers. `ghci` will always infer the more general type.

Comment: This is a good point; ghci will always help you maximise code reuse this way.